# How can I display elements of a hidden class one at a time?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to build a quiz in jquery such that the user sees only one question at a time. I have populated the 'divs' using PHP. I can hide the list of questions with: 
`$(".questions).hide();`

But when I select the id of any element inside the hidden class, it is not displayed.

Here's a dummy HTML:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".questions").hide();
  $("#question1").show(); // this is not working.


  $(".option").click(answeredQuestionBox);
  $(".check-box").click(reviewQuestionBox);

});
```

```html
<div class="questions">
  <div id="question1">
    // question goes here with 'radio' input options.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hide the child `div` of `questions` element.

```
$(".questions > div").hide(); //$(".questions").children("div").hide()
$("#question1").show();
```

I would recommend you to assign a CSS class to question.

```
<div class="questions">
  <div class="question" id="question1">
      // question goes here with 'radio' input options.
  </div>
</div>
```

then you can use

```
$(".questions > div.questions").not("#question1").hide();
```

Comment: It worked. I was under the impression that hiding the parent div hides all the child elements automatically, and I can then selectively display them using their 'id's. Can you point me in the right direction, as to why this is not the case? Many thanks.